# Find specific tokens in text and validate them (RegExp?)

Tags: c++, regex, pattern-matching

I have a few textfiles containing `C++ code` where i have to check each hardcoded `string` (`static const char*`) for placeholders and validate the ordering.

We use `boost::format` for the placeholder tokens that are basically a '%' followed by a number (1 to n) and again a '%'.

Now i need to find all the strings where they are not in ascending order.

For example:

```
// this is a valid string containing tokens
string valid = "this %1% \"contains\" %2% %3%";
// this is not ...
string invalid = "this %1% \"contains\" %3% %2%";
```

So, is it possible to find that using `RegExp`?

**edit**:
So i have my `regexp` that should find all the text containing tokensand an idea how to validate the ordering.

is there an more elegant way to write the `regexp` than `"((([^"]|\\")*)?%\d%)+([^"]|\\")*"` ? (it whould work according the online tester, but maybe there is a way to improve my noobish knowledge)

Comment: You can get a list of all matches, and just loop over the list to see that the numbers are in increasing order. It's not possible to do directly with regular expressions only.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg like use `grep` to get all the content with tokens into a file and use for example `python` to do the rest?

Comment: Why not use Python directly with its [regular expression module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)? Or any other language with regular expression support, which is just about any language these days.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg yup, definatly more straight forward. would you write an 'answere' to let me mark that as done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many languages include regular expression modules, for example Python has the [`re` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html). These regular expression modules allow you to search for multiple matches to a regular expression, and returns a list of all matching expressions. You could then loop over this list and make sure that the number matching the regular expression come in increasing order.